# Space Hotel - Amenities

Tags: internal-consistency, space-constructs

What luxury amenities could a hotel in space offer (that obviously weren't available on Earth) that patrons could experience within the hotel or within their rooms for the right price? Specifically, things that actually feel like amenities, as opposed to the view, or micro-gravity which could come standard with all rooms.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As it stands now, your question is both asking to compile a list with no clear limit and is also strongly opinion based, since what is amenities and what standard service vary from hotel to hotel already on Earth. Please read the [help] to better understand how to improve your question.